# JavaScript for loop: why is the type of index string in this case?

Tags: javascript

```
var string = "The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog";
var words = string.split(" ");
for (var i in words) {
    console.log(typeof i) // "string"
    console.log(i) // 0,1,2,3...n
}
```

I just found out that the type of i in the for loop is a string in this case. Why?

Comment: Because you're using the wrong loop. Try with a regular `for` loop.

Comment: i is not an index but the actual value

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Property names are strings and the `for (var i in words)` loop you're using iterates the property names of the `words` object (which happens to include the array indexes).  You should not be using `for (var i in words)` to iterate the elements of an array because it iterates properties, not only array elements.

You can use either of these forms to iterate the elements of an array:

```
for (var i = 0; i < words.length; i++) {
   item = words[i];
}
```

Or, in modern browsers, you can use:

```
words.forEach(function(value, index) {

});
```

Comment: I thought there was nothing bad with iterating by (for var i in array), according to this [guide](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/A_re-introduction_to_JavaScript#Arrays) provided by Mozilla. Could you elaborate a little more for me?

Comment: @wonie - `for (i in array)` iterates all iterable properties of the array object, not only array elements.  If your intention is to iterate only array elements, then you should not use `for (i in array)`.  Sometimes it works, but sometimes it is not so it is NOT advised or considered best practice.  As to your MDN reference, read exactly what it says there.  If properties have been added, it will iterate those too.  It is NOT a good practice.

Comment: @wonie That's bad advice. If array methods are being polyfilled in e.g. older IEs, those names will pop up in the for-in loop. Avoid it.